# Blender 3.0 Where is "Smooth Normals" option in Remesh

Tags: sculpting, remesh

[image]

I can't find Smooth Normals checkbox.
Is that update? or anyway how can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's been removed in 3.0.

[Old docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/remesh.html) / [New docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/remesh.html)

You'll have to enable [smooth shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/scene_layout/object/editing/shading.html#shade-smooth) manually afterwards in object mode, Right Click > Smooth Shading