# Sculpt Tool + Artifacts Material

Tags: sculpt

i am trying to add some folds and imperfections to this mesh.
After using the sculpt tool, I find artifacts on my mesh. It has its transforms / scaling applied, and re-wrapping it doesn't seem to help.

The material is textured with a procedural noise node.

Any ideas on why it's happening?

[image]

File shared here:
[image]

Comment: Any one with an idea why it's happening?

Comment: *"It has no transforms or scaling applied"* - they should be applied, but I imagine that's what you mean (in this case edit to *"It has all transforms applied"* or just remove *"applied"*). Uploading your .blend file will help. Marking the *"artifacts"* on the screenshot will help. For example do you mean those [discontinuities](https://i.imgur.com/LEQ0heI.png)? Explaining your workflow (how you sculpt, do you use dyntopo etc.) will help.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady yes, you are correct. Updated comments to reflect that. File attached below. This version is simply the flat geometry before any sculpting has been applied. Dyntopo was played around with but the results were the same in either case.

Answer (score 1):

If you activate the *Wireframe* and *Face Orientation* overlays in the [overlays menu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598) you will see the two problems:

1. **flipped normals**, they all point inwards (red) but should point outwards (blue)
2. the top and the bottom are **huge n-gons** and there is **not enough geometry to sculpt** anything

[image: mesh with wireframe and face orientation overlays]

The activation of *Dyntopo* will split the n-gon into large diagonal triangles that causes the artifacts that you see on your screenshot.
The *Cloth* brush does not add geometry when used with *Dyntopo*. Even when you "touch" (strength=0) the mesh with the *Draw* brush to add geometry then the *Cloth* brush effect is fairly weak.

**To prepare the model for sculpting**, you can do the following:

- *optional:* duplicate the model if you want to keep it low-poly and bake the sculpted details into a normal map later.
- switch to *Sculpt* mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to visually adjust the *voxel size* of the remesher. A grid is displayed where you can choose the size with the mouse. Try a value of `0.0300`. Confirm it with LMB or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (The *Dyntopo* option must be turned *off* for this to work). 
  Alternatively, you can enter this value in [the settings of the remesher](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245512/107598).
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to execute the **remesh** operation. The remesh will fix the normals and generate a nice grid structure mesh but will also delete all UV maps!
- *optional:* if you don't want a low-poly version but keep the texture on this sculpted model you need to UV unwrap it again now. Go to the *UV Editor*, select top view and do an *Unwrap > Project from View*. Scale the UV island to fit the texture.
- sculpt the details. The *Cloth* and *Cloth Filter* brushes should work fine.
  [image: sculpted mesh]
- *optional:* bake the normal map from the sculpted model to the low-poly model
- select *Shaded Smooth* for the object (with the context menu in *Object* mode)

Comment: Thank you for your help!